# performance of mysql query result using max, group by, temporary table and random row selection

Tags: mysql, random, group-by

I am selecting unique productid w.r.t sizeid from below table, but i need to select random row when prices are same.

```
aff_id,  wl_product_id, wl_size_id,  price
1           40             10        57
3           41             11        65
4           41             11        67
1           41             11        67
```

I am expecting below result if price are same, will result random aff_id(4 or 1 in above example).

```
 aff_id,  wl_product_id, wl_size_id,  price,   random_number
    1           40         10        57        37.5708656809953
    4(random)   41         11        67        88.2194444427453
```

**Below query results same as above. but is good with respect to performance as i am using temporary table.**

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT ap1.aff_id,ap1.wl_product_id,ap1.wl_size_id, ap1.price,(ap1.price*RAND())AS random_number 
   FROM affiliate_product ap1
   INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT wl_product_id, MAX(price) AS price FROM affiliate_product  WHERE wl_product_id>0 GROUP BY wl_product_id,wl_size_id) ap2
   ON (ap1.wl_product_id = ap2.wl_product_id AND ap1.price = ap2.price) ORDER BY wl_product_id,random_number
)AS temp_tbl GROUP BY wl_product_id,wl_size_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `group_concat()` and `substring_index()`:

```
select wl_product_id, wl_size_id, price,
       substring_index(group_concat(aff_id order by rand()), ',', 1) as aff_id
from t
group by wl_product_id, wl_size_id, price;
```

One note:  This will convert the `aff_id` into a character representation.  If you are using for join's afterwards, then you might want to convert it back to a number.

EDIT:

To get the information for the max price, then use a `join` to get that information:

```
select t.*
from (select wl_product_id, wl_size_id, price,
             substring_index(group_concat(aff_id order by rand()), ',', 1) as aff_id
      from t
      group by wl_product_id, wl_size_id, price
     ) t join
     (select wl_product_id, wl_size_id, max(price) as maxprice
      from t
      group by wl_product_id, wl_size_id
     ) tmax
      on tmax.wl_product_id = t.wl_product_id and
         tmax.wl_size_id = t.wl_size_id  and
         tmax.maxprice = t.price;
```

Comment: very nice idea, I thought of `group_concat` but didn't know how to get 1 random id. +1 for my knowledge :D

Comment: sorry about wrong posting of result. i corrected it in question. actually i need 41(product_id)/11(size_id) row with max(price). tried that with your query but not getting the result.

Comment: thanks. working fine. i am trying to compare it with my query given above but with small data showing no real difference with speed. EXPLAIN shows your query saves "one temporary table and a filesort" wrt my query. will try benchmark tests and let you know.